# iphone refresh table when view restored

Tags: iphone, viewdidload

I have several views that are called modally.  View 1 calls View 2 and View 2 calls View 3

View 1 has a table view with data from a database.

View 3 could change the data that is shown on the table on View 1.  So when View 3 and View 2 are release View 1 still shows the old data.

I assume there is a function that is available when a view is visible again?  Can anyone please point me the right direction?

For example  (void)viewDidLoad is triggered when its first loaded.  How about when its re-displayed?

thank you!

Comment: perhaps overload one of these on the top level controller?
`-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{}`
`-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this to your view:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can post notification after the data changing, then let the View 1 to update when receiving the data changing notification. Check the documentation of `NSNotificationCenter`.